# Wait for async value before running other function

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to initialise 2 different values in a component, both of which are retrieved asynchronously from firestore, but the snapshot method that I'm using to get the second requires the value of the first.

Because these are asynchronous, the method to get the second is running before the value it depends upon is actually retrieved, so this results in the following error, as this.invoice is trying to be initialised before the request to get this.userId is complete:

```
"Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Observable<Invoice>'"...
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { InvoiceService } from '../invoice.service';

import { Invoice } from '../invoiceModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-invoice',
  templateUrl: './view-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class ViewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  userId: string;
  invoiceId: string;
  invoice: Observable<Invoice>;
  items: object[];

  itemsData = new MatTableDataSource();

  tableColumns = [
    'description'
  ]

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private invoiceService: InvoiceService, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userId = this.authService.user.uid;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.invoiceId = params.id;
    })

    this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.invoice = snapshot.data() as Observable<Invoice>;
        this.invoice.subscribe(invoice => {
            this.itemsData.data = invoice.items;
        })
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.itemsData.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.itemsData.sort = this.sort;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try like this

```
this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.invoice = snapshot.data() as Observable<Invoice>.subscribe(invoice => {
            this.itemsData.data = invoice.items;
        })
    })
```

Comment: Because the userId property is the one that isn't resolving before this depends on it. This is the issue I'm having

Comment: do you get the value for userId?

Comment: No. As I just said, userId isn't being resolved before the above method begins. It's only initialised after this tries to run

Answer (score 0):

To create the firebase observable based on the result of the router observable, you can use an operator from the [`flatMap`](https://namitamalik.github.io/Map-vs-FlatMap/) familly (`mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap`, etc.)

In your case, I think [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) would be the best choice, it take an observable, and when it emits, it create a new observable based on the emitted value.

```
this.route.params
    .switchMap(params => {
        // Async fetch on firebase, based on the route param
        const invoiceId = params.id;
        return Observable.fromPromise(
            this.db.collection('/users')
                .doc(this.userId)
                .collection('/invoices')
                .doc(invoiceId)
                .ref.get()
        );
    }).switchMap(snapshot => {
        // Async observable of the snapshot.
        return snapshot.data() as Observable<Invoice>;
    }).subscribe(invoice => {
        this.itemsData.data = invoice.items;
    })
```

*I wrote the code based on your type hint, it won't work if you mess with the types, but the logic is here.*

Comment: Thanks, but it's not based on the route observable, it it's the userId that needs to be initialised before populating this.invoice. It also returns the following error in the console: 'You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable'

Comment: In your code, `...doc(this.invoiceId)...` use the variable taken from the route param `invoiceId`, so it is based on the route. Where does this error occur ?

Comment: I've just said that the problem is not with the invoiceId. The problem is that the method containing the subscribe is running before the userId is resolved at the top of the constructor. The method containing the subscribe is dependent on the userId